# How to chant/pronounce words like kṛt and bhṛt in sanskrit stotras?

Tags: vedas, mantras, stotra

In sanskrit dictionary, the words pronounced like krith and bhrith gives the right meaning for the respective stotras, but in most of the stotra audios,people used to chant kruth and bhruth, which has different meanings? Please clarify

Comment: North Indians pronounce ऋ as 'Ri' while South Indians pronounce the same as 'Ru'.